# COUNT in a clause HAVING + GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to build a query that will capture ONLY the SKU(Product) for which there is more than 1 Manufacturer Barcode in the DB.
I am trying to use a variable but it does not work

```
Table 1 (wms_inventory)
SKU1
SKU2
SKU3
```

_

```
Table 2 (ims_manufacturer_barcode)
SKU1 MB1
SKU1 MB2
SKU2 MB3
SKU3 MB4
SKU3 MB5
SKU3 MB6
```

_

```
Result expected
SKU1 | 2
SKU3 | 3

-> no SKU2 in the results because there is only 1 Manufacturer Barcode.
```

_

```
SELECT
i.fk_current_warehouse AS `Warehouse`,
i.sku AS `SKU`,
@var := COUNT(DISTINCT b.manufacturer_barcode) AS `Number of different Manufacturer Barcode`
FROM wms_inventory i
LEFT JOIN ims_manufacturer_barcode b ON i.sku = b.sku
HAVING @var > 1
GROUP BY i.sku
;
```

_

The above query raise the following error

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version
for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY i.sku' at line 8
```

Comment: write `having` only after `group by`. Variable not need. `select ..., count(...) from ... join ... group by i.sku having count(DISTINCT b.manufacturer_barcode)>1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below query will help you...

```
  SELECT B.COL1, COUNT(DISTINCT B.COL2) AS CNT FROM TABLE2 B
GROUP BY B.COL1 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.COL2) >1
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below query.

```
SELECT t2.SKU, COUNT(*) total
  FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.SKU = t2.SKU 
 GROUP BY t2.SKU
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: In an inner query, those SKUs having more then one manufacturer are prepared. The outer query then gets all the records which's SKU is one of those of the inner query:

```
select * from table2 result
where result.SKU in
  (select sku
   from table2 cnt
   group by cnt.sku
   having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT my_column, COUNT(*) total
  FROM table2 
 GROUP BY my_column
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  -- if distinct is required then you probably have bigger design problems
```